# org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate:destroy:178- Destroying delegate

Tags: spring-security, logback, spring-saml

I have a spring application configured with SAML for authentication. 
It uses logback for logging. The logging happens only for a day or so, after which it stops automatically with the following msg in the log:

```
[LOG] [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger:log:87] - Closing      WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Jun 22 04:50:14 UTC 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil:marshallMessage:390] - XMLObject already had cached DOM, returning that element
[LOG] [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger:log:87] - ClosingRoot WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jun 22 04:50:00 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate:destroy:178] - Destroying delegate
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate:destroy:178] - Destroying delegate
[LOG] [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate:destroy:178] - Destroying delegate
```

I have to restart tomcat in order to resume logging. Every time, the logging stops with the above messages only. So, I suspect something with the SAML integration. 
Any pointers on how to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with the Spring or Spring SAML at all. 
I had used a relative file path in the logback configuration. 
Looks like the log rotation doesn't work properly with relative file path.

Using an absolute file path solved the issue.